# cramersV function not 1 for the same variable

Tags: r, correlation

I am calculating the correlation matrix of two discrete variables with the cramersV function in Rstudio. When I enter in the input of the function a dataset with 2 columns containing the same values (i.e. representing the same variable), the output is not 1 but 0.999. How is it possible ? Such variable contains 2 possible character values, "1" and "2".

I am running

```
cramersV(x,x)
```

where x is a vector of 3451 character values ("1" or "2")

```
head(x)
[1] "2" "2" "2" "1" "2" "2"
```

The output is

```
  [1] 0.9991948
```

Comment: Please share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also share your current code.

Comment: What package are you using for calculating cramersV? Please share the full code including the packages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a how-to on trying to solve R problems on your own the next time.

You should first check the help function of `cramersV` via `?cramersV` (assuming you are using the `lsr` package).

It states that:

> Calculates the Cramer's V measure of effect size for chi-square tests
> of association and goodness of fit. The arguments to the cramersV
> function are all passed straight to the chisq.test function, and
> should have the same format.

So now we should of course check what the default values of `chisq.test` are. And as you can see, there's a parameter `correct` that is set to `TRUE` by default and does the following:

> a logical indicating whether to apply continuity correction when
> computing the test statistic for 2 by 2 tables: one half is subtracted
> from all |O - E| differences; however, the correction will not be
> bigger than the differences themselves. No correction is done if
> simulate.p.value = TRUE.

So you now have two potential solutions that you can try. The easiest one is setting the parameter `correct` to `FALSE`.

Thus, if you use `cramersV(x, x, correct = FALSE)`, you get the expected value of `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. At the end, did you understand what is the continuity correction ?

Comment: PLease try Wikipedia on "continuity correction". This should be a good start.